# Why does it not allow me to add a module to the set?

Tags: java, set, addition

Module is an abstract class that has two subclasses. I want to add a module to the set, but it does not compile where I call add function. Why?

```
    public void recordModules(Student student, 
        Set<? extends Module> modules) {
    if (student != null && modules != null){
        Set<Student> students = records.keySet();
        if (students.contains(student)){

            Set<Student> s = new HashSet<Student>();
            s.add(student);
            List<? extends Module> subjects = getModulesTakenBy(s);
            Iterator<? extends Module> it = subjects.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                Module m = it.next();
                modules.add(m);}
        }
            records.put(student, modules);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could be wrong, but try changing <? extends Module> to <Module>, with particular reference to the set ... Or any other collection where you are trying to add content to it...

Comment: I cannot change it to <Module> by ... the rules of my practical. I have a JUnit test written for this and I have to pass the test.

Comment: WHAT'S THE BLINKIN' ERROR MESSAGE?

Comment: The method add(capture#6-of ? extends Module) in the type Set<capture#6-of ? extends Module> is not applicable for the arguments (Module)

Comment: Well, in that case, I think you might be screwed...